# How can i implement the p-galleria(primeng) control using vertical scrolling? will anyone please guide me?

Tags: primeng, galleria

I want to implement the p-galleria control with vertical scrolling in angular using primeng. I tried working various samples in the site https://primeng.org/galleria.

But not able to implement. will anyone give me guidance on it?

Thanks,
Vinod

I tried it with horizontal scrolling. but How can i implement with vertical scrolling.